# Newtonsoft Object → Get JSON string

Tags: json, json.net

I have an object that is created by Newtonsoft's JSON serializer. I need to get the JSON string that was used to create the object. How do I serialize the object into a simple JSON string?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string jsonOut()
{
    // Returns JSON string.
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);       
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: @Demodave: SomeObject.jsonOut()