# Storing original JSON string in deserialised JSON.NET objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

This is basically a follow-on to the question [Newtonsoft Object → Get JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690395/newtonsoft-object-%E2%86%92-get-json-string) .

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter))]
public class Message
{
    public Message(string original)
    {
        this.Original = original;
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Original { get; set; }
}
```

My requirement is to store the original JSON string as part of the object when I initialise it. I have been able to (partially) successfully achieve this using a custom `JsonConverter` and then basically doing something like this in the `JsonConverter`:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.Null)
        return null;

    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
    return new Message(obj.ToString(Formatting.None))
    {
        Type = obj["type"].ToString()
    };
}
```

However the problem I run into is when I try to inherit from `Message` with something like

```
public class CustomMessage : Message
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

For obvious reasons my code fails because it tries to return a new `Message()` not a new `CustomMessage()`.

So short of implementing a big if statement with all my sub-types and manually binding using something like `JObject["prop"].ToObject<T>()` how can I successfully populate the `Original` property while still binding all my sub-type values using the default deserialisation?

***NOTE: The reason this is being done is because the original message might contain data that isn't actually being bound so I can't just add a property which serialises the object as it stands.***

Comment: is this a typo??
 **return new GDAXMessage** or is it **return new Message** ??

Comment: Yeah sorry typo fixed it.

Comment: Take a look at [How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains “raw” JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529125/3744182).  You should be able to apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))]` to `Original`.

Comment: @dbc That helps a bit because it makes sense that I should just add to the property a custom serialiser but the problem is that Original is not part of the JSON message and gets skipped. Basically I need the example you provided but with a runtime defaultvalue provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving the question open in the hope that someone comes up with a better answer but I've temporarily used the following solution to resolve my problem.

```
public static class MessageExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string message) where T : Message
    {
        T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        instance.Original = message;
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(message, instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works

One thing you can do is to decorate each child class by generic `JsonConverter` attribute.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter<Message>))]
public class Message
{
    public Message(string original)
    {
        this.Original = original;
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Original { get; set; }
}
[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter<CustomMessage>))]
public class CustomMessage : Message
{
    public CustomMessage(string original) : base(original)
    {
    }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class MessageConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : Message
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var customObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings 
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver()
                        });
        customObject.Original = obj.ToString();
            return customObject;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

//This will remove our declared Converter
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter (Type objectType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you can use the same serializer for all of the child classes

```
CustomMessage x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomMessage>("{\"type\":\"Test\",\"Prop1\":\"Prop1\"}");
 Message y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>("{\"type\":\"Test\"}");
```

Here is the output screen shot
[image]

Comment: Although this is sorta on the right track. Thats not going to work because the remainder of the object properties will not be deserialised. Try changing your example code to "{\"type\":\"Test\", \"Prop1\":\"Test2\"}" and you'll see the issue.

Comment: @MaximGershkovich I think I found the solution :-) Please check the updated answer

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion and while I've upvoted your solution because it technically solves the problem. I'm not really sure that I like your solution better than mine. The answer is probably that its not worth the effort. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone else comes up with a better solution.